# Filtering Python Pandas dataframe by IP octet

Tags: python, pandas, ip

I have been Goog'ling this for a while, but haven't found the solution, so a hint in the right direction would be appreciated...

I have a Pandas dataframe with roughly 13.000 rows with 96 columns. One of the columns contains IP addresses that I would like to filter on.

I would like to remove all rows where the IP address matches these any of these:
10.x.220.x or 10.x.240.x

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add the data sample as text, not as a picture. E.g. try `df.to_dict()` and post in a block between triple backticks (```). Show both input *and* expected output. Also, show us what you have tried so far, and why your attempt isn't giving you the result that you expect. See: [Research Effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: Are these address always quartets of decimal values separated by `.` or other forms are also allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with a regex and [`str.fullmatch`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.fullmatch.html):

```
df2 = df[~df['ip_column'].str.fullmatch(r'10\.\d+\.(220|240)\.\d+')]
```

Example input:

```
  col     ip_column
0   A    10.1.220.1
1   B      10.0.0.1
2   C  10.127.240.0
3   D     127.0.0.1
```

Matching output:

```
  col  ip_column
1   B   10.0.0.1
3   D  127.0.0.1
```

regex:

```
10           # match 10
\.           # match a dot
\d+          # match one or more digits
\.           # match a dot
(220|240)    # match 220 or 240
\.           # match a dot
\d+          # match one or more digits
```